# Tags: supplements vs food-supplements

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have a supplements tag as well as a food-supplements tag.  Are they both needed, or should one be a synonym for the other?

Answer (score 1):

I think they should be made into synonyms and merged.

EDIT: Seeing no objections and having one upvote, I created the synonym and merged them.